# Subtracting two raster layers based on condition in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, conditional

I have 3 raster layers in QGIS. I want to subtract two from each other based on a condition in a third layer.

`'Layer1'`: has no data in some parts and I used `Close gaps` to generate `'Layer1_fill'`. What I want to do is to subtract the filled values in `'Layer1_fill'` from `'Layer2'` whenever `'Layer1'` has no data.

If `'Layer1'` has no data and `'Layer2'` has data, then `'Layer2' - 'Layer1_fill'`

To do so, I converted nodata in `'Layer1'` to 0 and called it `'layer1_null0'`.

I tried this expression in Raster Calculator but it didn't work

```
("layer1_null0@1" = 0 AND Layer2 != 0) * ("Layer2@1" - "Layer1_fill@1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need more brackets, and you can replace logical AND with numerical *.

```
(layer1_null = 0) * (layer2 != 0)
```

selects the pixels that meet the criteria.

```
(layer1_null = 0) * (layer2 != 0) * (layer2 - layer1)
```

gets the difference for the relevant pixels.

To choose between layers, you could use:

```
(layer1 = 0) * layer2 + (layer1 != 0) * layer3
```

For example, you might want layer 1 if it exists, but layer1_fill if it doesn't.

```
(layer1 = 0) * layer1_fill + (layer1 != 0) * layer1
```